# Return the first week with values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is possible to return the first week with value <> 0? What i need is the column "first week" (in green) filled automatically, with the week that is in the first line.

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH(TRUE,A2:E2<>0,0))` and drag it down or `=BYROW(A2:E6,LAMBDA(x,INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MATCH(TRUE,x<>0,0))))` to spill column at once.

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thks for your help